# How to get more details regarding jquery ajax error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my sample ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: validateAjaxURL,
    success: function (data) {                  
        var returnData = data;  
        if (returnData.match("^selectedUno-")) {                                
              $('#new_caregiver_popup_div').dialog('close');    
        } else {
            $("#new_caregiver_popup_div").html(data);
        }
    },
    error: function() {                 
        alert('Unable to contact server');
    }
});
```

This is working fine. But if an error occurs it will only give the alert "Unable to contact server", so I want to get more details about the error such as what type of error, reason for the error etc. How can I do that?

Comment: See the entry for `error` in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. It gives you access to the XHR, and two text statuses about the state of the request

Comment: try `error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }`

Comment: what we get from request.responseText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually write the "error" function something like this:

```
function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}
```

This is as per the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. There are 3 parameters you can read from in order to find out more. Depending on the nature of the error, sometimes it's more informative than others.

Also depending on your browser, looking in the console and the networking logging in the developer tools (F12 on most browsers) may also give you some clues.

Comment: "parsererror" ,"timeout", "abort" Can we get these errors also using the above function?

Comment: @Thiwanka it's up to the server what error it returns. But it would probably tell you about a timeout. I'm not sure about the others to be honest. P.S. if my answer has helped you please upvote and/or mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: can i show this error in a div element in the html page? how to do that?

Comment: sure, you can do anything you like with it. It's just text. e.g. if you have a div like this `<div id="error" hidden></div>` then you can make it show, and give it the error as content. Replace the contents of the function with this: `$("#error").show(); $("#error").text("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);`

Comment: Thanks a lot again. can you give a help to this scenario as well? i am going to define separate pages related with errors(404, 500, etc). And if i receive an error in ajax call, i should redirect to the previously define page based on the error type. can this be done using j query? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can do that, but it's bad for user experience. One error in an ajax call shouldn't mean the user loses everything they are doing on that page. It's sufficient (and expected practise) just to display the error and let the user decide what to do. Maybe you include some details on how to report the error. Hopefully an error will be a very rare thing!

Comment: you mean that it is OK to just give the error and details on how to report the error as an "alert"?

Comment: or in a div, whichever you prefer. But yes that's acceptable for an ajax error. Better than an unexpected redirect. For errors with normal "full" page loads, you should use redirects.

Comment: i want trigger error: method in ajax call manually in order to check my error details. can you please tell a way to do this?

Comment: I think you could either 1) alter your server-side code for testing purposes so it _always_ throws the error, then you can guarantee to test it, or 2) create conditions that you know will cause the error you want (e.g. provide bad data, disconnect from network, whatever you want to achieve)

Comment: Many thanks to you. My requirement got changed.now i have to create predefined html or jsp pages regarding common errors(404,500) for the entire application and once the above mentioned ajax called met with error that predefined error page should be displayed. do i need to changed the web.xml? can you please explain this too ?

Comment: Again I would advise you not to redirect the user to a different page when there's an ajax error. They will lose anything they are doing on that page (unlike with a full postback, where they have already submitted everything anyway). Also they won't be expecting it. If someone has given you this technical requirement you should explain to them why this is a bad thing. An alternative approach would be to create standard HTML snippets for each error type, which you can display in a modal popup whenever an ajax error occurs. For errors on full postback, use the redirects.

Comment: thanx. And if i want to get failure details of extjs ajax call how can i do that? there is a failure: property instead of error property.

Comment: Sorry I've never used extjs. I suggest you either read the documentation or ask a separate question if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this, it will give you exact error messages :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: validateAjaxURL,
success: function (data) {                  
    var returnData = data;  
    if (returnData.match("^selectedUno-")) {                                
          $('#new_caregiver_popup_div').dialog('close');    
    } else {
        $("#new_caregiver_popup_div").html(data);
    }
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
});
```

here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnValidate1").click(function () {
                var number = $("#txtNumber1").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: " Default.aspx/ValidateNumber",
                    data: '{number: "' + number + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert("Valid number.");
                    },
                    error: OnError
                });
            });
        });
        function OnError(xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var responseText;
            $("#dialog").html("");
            try {
                responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                $("#dialog").append("<div><b>" + errorType + " " + exception + "</b></div>");
                $("#dialog").append("<div><u>Exception</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.ExceptionType + "</div>");
                $("#dialog").append("<div><u>StackTrace</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.StackTrace + "</div>");
                $("#dialog").append("<div><u>Message</u>:<br /><br />" + responseText.Message + "</div>");
            } catch (e) {
                responseText = xhr.responseText;
                $("#dialog").html(responseText);
            }
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Exception Details",
                width: 700,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

here is the screen shot of an error[image]:

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Please upvote/accept this as answer. if it is helpful. thanks.

Comment: instead of an alert, can i show this error details on a html page? if it is possible how can i do that

Comment: use console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

Comment: error: function () {
      console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
     }                                                                                 is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is, what do you think its not working, please check the selector ID's if it is redirected correctly.

Comment: And if i want to get failure details of extjs ajax call how can i do that? there is a failure: property instead of error property in extjs ajax call