# How to Print java script error message in my div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this code is working great, i am new in javascript ,what i am trying to do , print js default error message in my  div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 var contranumber = <?php  echo json_encode($data); ?>;
                 debugger;
                 if(contranumber)
                 {

                     $.ajax({
                         url: ApiUrl+'ActivateUser?contraNumber='+contranumber,
                         type: 'get',
                         success: function (data, xhr) {
                         alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                         },
                         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             console.log('Error in Operation');
                         }
                     });
                 }else
                 {

                 }
             });
        </script>
    <div><center>javascript message</center></div>
    <center><h3> Check your Email</h3></center>
```

Comment: so, instead of the console.log you want to put that error in some undisclosed location?

Comment: Give the `<div>` and ID or class and target it that way, like `document.querySelector('.my-error').textContent = 'My Error'`. Also remove the center tags, the've been deprecated for years now.

Comment: alert(data.ErrorMessage); , i just want to print this data in this div <div><center>javascript message</center></div> any other easy away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few quick things first:

- Remove `center` tags, as it is [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER). (Official example is "No, really, don't use it.")
- Remove `debugger;`, unless you want your browser to stop.
- Give your elements some sort of identification, be it a class or ID.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contranumber = '{ "hello": "world" }';
  var message = $('.message'); // the element the message will go in

  if (contranumber) {
    $.ajax({
      url: ApiUrl + 'ActivateUser?contraNumber=' + contranumber,
      type: 'get',
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) { // you missed the textStatus parameter
        message.text('it was successful'); // why log an error on success?
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        message.text('Error in Operation:' + errorThrown); // give the actual error text
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message"></div>
<h3>Check your Email</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: validateAjaxURL,
success: function (data) {                  
var returnData = data;  
if (returnData.match("^selectedUno-")) {                                
      $('#new_caregiver_popup_div').dialog('close');    
} else {
    $("#new_caregiver_popup_div").html(data);
}
 },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
 });
```

UPDATE :

```
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#DivID').text(errorThrown);           
    }
```

Here is the link for your reference :

[Show Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479821/how-to-get-more-details-regarding-jquery-ajax-error/38480437#38480437)

Comment: you can change it to console.log(), our client needs pop-up so alert!

Comment: That's great for your client, but the OP isn't your client, and most users don't like pop-up's (especially errors).

Comment: @evoutionxbox, he can use alert or console as per his needs.

Comment: That's not what OP has asked... `what i am trying to do , **print js default error message in my div**`

Comment: alert(data.ErrorMessage); , i just want to print this message in this div <div><center>javascript message</center></div> any other easy away

Comment: you can use selector ID(divID) to pass the error, like $('#selector').text(error);

Answer (score 0):

$('#example center').text(data.ErrorMessage);

Comment: just add a id for the div in this case gave the name "example"<div id="example"><center></center></div>